# Train an Object Detection Classifier How to Make Money with Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

```
from object_detection.protos import calibration_pb2 as object__detection_dot_protos_dot_calibration__pb2
```

> ImportError: cannot import name 'calibration_pb2' from
>   'object_detection.protos'
>   (C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\object_detection-0.1-py3.7.egg\object_detection\protos__init__.py)

but **init**.py is an empty file !

This is error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6bQh3.png)

and this is **init**.py

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYndt.png)

I have this error. Is there any solution to clear this out

Comment: Hey Radhi, can you check if the files are being accessed from the correct location? That is local directory versus site-packages?

Comment: did you solve the issue cuz i am having the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 7 hours of complete reinstallations and changing versions and updating pilotes and and and ... I had to look closely where is the import of calibration_pb2. And after 10 minutes of investigations, I noticed that the **protoc cmd does not generate the file calibration_pb2.py** !!!!

To generate the file calibration_pb2.py

You need to replace :

```
protoc --python_out=. .\object_detection\protos\anchor_generator.proto .\object_detection\protos\argmax_matcher.proto .\object_detection\protos\bipartite_matcher.proto .\object_detection\protos\box_coder.proto .\object_detection\protos\box_predictor.proto .\object_detection\protos\eval.proto .\object_detection\protos\faster_rcnn.proto .\object_detection\protos\faster_rcnn_box_coder.proto .\object_detection\protos\grid_anchor_generator.proto .\object_detection\protos\hyperparams.proto .\object_detection\protos\image_resizer.proto .\object_detection\protos\input_reader.proto .\object_detection\protos\losses.proto .\object_detection\protos\matcher.proto .\object_detection\protos\mean_stddev_box_coder.proto .\object_detection\protos\model.proto .\object_detection\protos\optimizer.proto .\object_detection\protos\pipeline.proto .\object_detection\protos\post_processing.proto .\object_detection\protos\preprocessor.proto .\object_detection\protos\region_similarity_calculator.proto .\object_detection\protos\square_box_coder.proto .\object_detection\protos\ssd.proto .\object_detection\protos\ssd_anchor_generator.proto .\object_detection\protos\string_int_label_map.proto .\object_detection\protos\train.proto .\object_detection\protos\keypoint_box_coder.proto .\object_detection\protos\multiscale_anchor_generator.proto .\object_detection\protos\graph_rewriter.proto
```

With

```
protoc --python_out=. .\object_detection\protos\anchor_generator.proto .\object_detection\protos\argmax_matcher.proto .\object_detection\protos\bipartite_matcher.proto .\object_detection\protos\box_coder.proto .\object_detection\protos\box_predictor.proto .\object_detection\protos\eval.proto .\object_detection\protos\faster_rcnn.proto .\object_detection\protos\faster_rcnn_box_coder.proto .\object_detection\protos\grid_anchor_generator.proto .\object_detection\protos\hyperparams.proto .\object_detection\protos\image_resizer.proto .\object_detection\protos\input_reader.proto .\object_detection\protos\losses.proto .\object_detection\protos\matcher.proto .\object_detection\protos\mean_stddev_box_coder.proto .\object_detection\protos\model.proto .\object_detection\protos\optimizer.proto .\object_detection\protos\pipeline.proto .\object_detection\protos\post_processing.proto .\object_detection\protos\preprocessor.proto .\object_detection\protos\region_similarity_calculator.proto .\object_detection\protos\square_box_coder.proto .\object_detection\protos\ssd.proto .\object_detection\protos\ssd_anchor_generator.proto .\object_detection\protos\string_int_label_map.proto .\object_detection\protos\train.proto .\object_detection\protos\keypoint_box_coder.proto .\object_detection\protos\multiscale_anchor_generator.proto .\object_detection\protos\graph_rewriter.proto .\object_detection\protos\calibration.proto
```